# Updating saved images for Retina Display

Tags: iphone, uiimage, resolution, retina-display

I have an iPhone app that, among other things, allows users to store photos.  When a new photo is added to the app's data store, I cache a thumbnail version of the image so that the photo thumbnail grids load in a reasonable amount of time.

The problem is that these thumbnails look great on a pre-Retina Display screen, but they look a little blurry on RD displays.  It's not so bad that the images are unusable, but I would really like to be able to get the full benefit of Retina Display for images users saved with older versions of my app.

The problem is that re-creating all these thumbnails takes way too long.  In my tests, it took about a minute and a half to re-encode a sample database to high-res thumbnails (admittedly a large one) on my iPhone 4.  It will be even worse on older hardware.

How can I get around this?  Doing a one-time migration seems out of the question, given the performance results above.  Other options are shrinking the thumbnails lazily (i.e. as they're displayed on-screen) and then saving them to the database at that point.  Screens full of old images will be sluggish the first time they're viewed, and then snappier after that.

Are there other approaches to consider?  Anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Screens full of old images will be sluggish the first time they're viewed, and then snappier after that.

It doesn't have to be sluggish.

It's a *bit* of a pain, but you can do most of your processing in a background thread. Set the thread priority to something low (like 0.1) to avoid making the UI too slow. The easiest way to do this is to set up an NSOperation for each image you need to convert and add them to a NSOperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount=1.

If writes are not atomic, in -applicationDidEnterBackground: or -applicationWillTerminate: (or in something listening for the corresponding notifications notifications), do something like `[queue cancelAllOperations]; for (NSOperation * operation in queue) { [operation setThreadPriority:1]; } [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];`; you get about 10 seconds or so which should be enough for the image conversion to finish writing to disk (and thus avoid half-written files). For added protection, check `[operation isCancelled]` immediately before the write if it might take longer than 10 seconds. Obviously, in -applicationWillEnterForeground:, you should restart the conversion (remembering that some of the images have already been converted).

Concurrency issues are fun to track down...

(Note that `[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES]` isn't sufficient — it's likely to leave temporary files lying around if the app is killed during the write. I'd recommend storing thumbnails in Core Data if you can, but that might be out of the question for existing apps.)

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont like the idea that you try and convert the images.
2. User will quickly get impatient and say you app is buggy and takes ages to load.
3. I think you solve the situation without any re-processing of full sized images.
4. On older hardware you would not have a retina display (so no need to upsize the images). If they have a retina display then they have a fast iPhone iPod.

I would suggest you graphically solve the problem by how you display the thumbnail images. so instead of fullscreen put a border around this image and show it at its true resolution (dont upscale it).  Or show 4 images where you normally show 1 (since iPhone screen is 4x the resolution).

Instead of resampling the original massive image, you could do a bicubic upsample of the thumbnail making it 4x the size. This will make it slightly blurry but it should look better than the iPhone scaling which will look really bad. The upsample would be ultra fast as its working with a small image.

I cannot help you out on upsampling but there will be some code somewhere.

Cheers, John.

Comment: -1. Images are effectively treated as textures on the GPU, and (as far as I know) use bicubic interpolation by default.

Comment: DUDE!  Your mark me down and you are not right. Non retina display images are NOT displayed using bicubic interpolation. The are pixel doubled. 1 pixel becomes 4 pixels of the same colour and look pixelated and jagged. Bicubic would not pixel double and give you a much smoother looking image.  Please correct you vote down.